# Placing my hand on laptop reduces buzz noise from USB headset mic. Is it safe?

Tags: laptop, usb, microphone, noise, headset

I am using a laptop that I believe is having the ground loop issue. It zaps me if I touch the metallic frame when I stand on my ceramic floor.

I have a USB headset and the microphone picks up the buzzing static noise. Now, after wearing a pair of slippers (to prevent myself getting zapped again) and if I placed my hand on my laptop, the buzzing noise that was previously picked up by the microphone is reduced drastically. At times when I need to use the microphone, I tend to place my hand on my laptop to reduce the static noise. Is it safe for me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not an electrician, I would **highly** discourage using the microphone.  If there was a peak in voltage, there could be consequences more severe.

If possible, I would recommend trying to disable the microphone, or, if nessasary, open the laptop up and disconnect the microphone from the motherboard.

Better safe than sorry.

Comment: It is just a buzzing noise running at the background. I don't think it is necessary for me to go all the way removing my microphone from the motherboard. Ok, maybe saying the word "zapped" might sound severe, it was just a tingling sense if I touch it while standing on the ceramic floor, because ceramic picks up electric currents. I think my body acted as the "ground" now and that's why the static noise is reduced when I touch the metallic frame of my laptop. The background noise is greatly reduced and my voice got through even more clearly from the mic now.

Comment: @MelissaM The thing is, if the voltage for some reason increases, you could be in for a nasty surprise...

Comment: I had this problem and it was caused by a faulty wall socket